# Host without a valid MX still seems to receive mail. How?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, mx-record, mail-forwarding

One of our clients owns the domain some-domain.org.

This domain is not maintained by us, and I am wondering if I am overlooking something: our client has a forwarder setup for this domain (IE. info@some-domain.org forwards to client@someisp.com).

When I do an MX lookup on this domain I see the following:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some-domain.org.   IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
some-domain.org. 9264 IN    MX      50 mail.some-domain.org.
```

Which indicates there has been an MX-entry setup. However, this specific entry does not seem to resolve:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.some-domain.org. IN   A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
some-domain.org. 2359 IN    SOA     ns1.hans.hosteurope.de. hostmaster.some-domain.org. 2010062314 16384 2048 1048576 2560
```

But yet, the forwarder works.

Am I overlooking something? **How can this forwarder work, even though this domain does not seem to have a valid MX entry?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If MX records are not present the delivery falls back to the A record.

Comment: Yep, check out the rfc for detailed info http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-5